# Join Tables in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a table with following format:

```
---------------------------------------------
|name |  date  | timeTable |clockIn|clockOut|
---------------------------------------------
|jhon |01/02/15| Mornning  | 08:29 |______  |
---------------------------------------------
|jhon |01/02/15| Afternoon |_______|  04:31 |
---------------------------------------------
|Harry|01/02/15| Mornning  | 08:23 |_______ |
---------------------------------------------
|Harry|01/02/15| Afternoon |_______|  04:29 |
---------------------------------------------
```

From this above table, my desired format is:

```
---------------------------------------------
|name |  date  | clockIn|clockOut|
---------------------------------------------
|jhon |01/02/15|  08:29 |  04:31 |
---------------------------------------------
|Harry|01/02/15|  08:23 |  04:29 |
---------------------------------------------
```

My working is as follows: 
**Controller**

```
 var t1 = (from a in hc.attendanceLogs
                  where (a.timeTable == "Morning")
                  select new
                  {
                      name = a.name,
                      date = a.date,
                      timeTable = a.timeTable,
                      clockIn = a.clockIn
                  }).ToList();

    var t2 = (from a in hc.attendanceLogs
              where a.timeTable == "Afternoon"
              select new
              {
                  date = a.date,
                  clockOut = a.clockOut
              }).ToList();

    DataTable finalTable = new DataTable();
                        finalTable.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
                        finalTable.Columns.Add("date", typeof(string));
                        finalTable.Columns.Add("clockIn", typeof(string));
                        finalTable.Columns.Add("clockOut", typeof(string));

                        var t3 = from a in t1
                                 join d in t2
                                 on
                                 a.date equals d.date
                                 select
                                 finalTable.LoadDataRow(
                                     new object[]
                                 { a.name, a.date, a.clockIn, d.clockOut },
                                     false);
    ViewBag.Data = finalTable;
```

What I'm trying to do is, cut first 4 columns of the initial table `hc.attendanceLogs` and popluate them in variable `t1`. Then I take the last column of the initial table `hc.attendanceLogs` and popluate it in variable `t2`. Finally, join t1 with t2 into `finalTable`, where date in t1 is equal to date in t2.

Problem is `ViewBag.Data` is coming as empty when I try to display `finalTable` in a View.
Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: How is `ViewBag.Data` empty? Does it not have a value? Or does it contain an empty `DataTable`?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Yes without iterating through `t3` (Adding `.ToList()` at the end of `var t3 = ..`, `finalTable` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because you are not actually evaluating or iterating through t3.

Try adding a `.ToList()` and the end of the `var t3 == ...` line.

Comment: It has shown the data but table is not in the correct format as described in the question. Like I have 2 entries for `Sameer` in the initial table, one for `clockIn`, and other for `clockout`. My desired format is to convert these two enteries into one entry showing `clockIn` and `clockOut` next to each other. But with my working, I am getting [this](http://postimg.org/image/v1ld78401/).

Comment: Your current join is ignoring the name. I think you need to add name to t2 and change your join to join on both name and date, eg  `on new { a.date, a.name} equals new { d.date, d.name} `